# SDL: Two Event Loops?

Tags: c++, sdl

Take a look at this piece of code here:

```
void game::startLoop()
{
 while(QUIT == false)
 {
  getRoomUpdate();
  applySurface(-15, 280, zombie_lefthand, buffer);
  applySurface(455, 280, zombie_righthand, buffer);

  SDL_Flip(buffer);

  while(SDL_PollEvent(&gameEvent))
  {
   if(gameEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
   {
    QUIT = true;
   }
  }

  while(SDL_WaitEvent(&keyEvent))
  {
   switch(keyEvent.type)
   {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    switch(keyEvent.key.keysym.sym)
    {
     //blahkeypress
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to allow SDL_QUIT to work while we're waiting for a keypress. Is there a way to do this or do you guys have a better idea?

I'm a bit of a newbie so please be specific. :D

Comment: **NEVER** wait for an event. Let the events come to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `keyEvent` is misleading.  `SDL_WaitEvent` will wait for any sort of event, including QUIT.

```
SDL_Event event;
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        quit = true;
        break;
    /* cases for keyboard events, etc. */
}
```

Comment: Well yes, but the problem is that I can't get to SDL_QUIT. I'll hit that silly X and it won't quit. I have to stop it in VC++.

Comment: @Lemmons: No idea if there's something special you have to do in Windows, but I would be surprised.  Works fine for me in X11.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal changes:

You could add `if (QUIT) break;` after the inner while loop that sets QUIT.

Or, you could move the outer while loop to a separate function and add a `return;` after `QUIT = true;`.

Better changes:

Refactor your code similar to many examples available on the web (at sourceforge, or at molly rocket, or just google it).